# Gear S3: Tizen native service: listen for key event in background

Tags: service, background, native, tizen

with native service app, running in a background, is it possible to listen for: 
1) BACK and HOME key? 
2) Bezel event? 
Most importantly, with the screen off - CPU in sleep. Is it even possible to catch the event which caused screenOn?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can detect Key Events and Rotary Events for Tizen wearable using Efl Extensions.

Please check these out:

[Efl Extension Hardware Keyevent](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/3.0.0/org.tizen.native.wearable.apireference/group__EFL__EXTENSION__HARDWARE__KEYEVENT__GROUP.html)

[Efl Extension Rotary Event](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/3.0.0/org.tizen.native.wearable.apireference/group__CAPI__EFL__EXTENSION__ROTARY__EVENT__MODULE.html)

Comment: I tried Efl Extensions, but it only works when the screen is on. My question was how to catch the event with screen off. Anyway, thank you for idea.

Comment: You can request CPU resource for your app to be responsive when screen is off (though it should be generally available for service app) using: device_power_request_lock ( POWER_LOCK_CPU,0 );

Comment: Links: https://developer.tizen.org/zh-hans/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/3.0.0/org.tizen.native.wearable.apireference/group__CAPI__SYSTEM__DEVICE__POWER__MODULE.html#ga87d358dabebb415e623498c5163503fb and https://developer.tizen.org/zh-hans/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/3.0.0/org.tizen.native.wearable.apireference/group__CAPI__SYSTEM__DEVICE__POWER__MODULE.html#gabc47c58cfcfdaaba177f6004d6395af2